# Loops on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, automation

I have the following query where I input a date and it give me the result. However, I need to run this for 60 different dates. Instead of running this 1 by 1, is there anyway to automate this so it runs each time on a different date?

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #1
    declare @d1 datetime = '2020-02-06' 
  select distinct [User] into #1
  from [X].[dbo].[Table1]
  where [status] = 'Success'
  and [Date] = @d1;

  select count(distinct [User])
  from #1
  inner join [Y].[dbo].[Table2]
  on #1.[User] = [Y].[dbo].[Table2].User
  where [Date2] between @d1 and @d1+1
  and [Checkname] in ('Check1','Check2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops are slow and generally a bad practice in the context of T-SQL. You can use something like this to get the count of users for a batch of dates:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [Date] DATETIME
   ,[UsersCount] INT
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([Date])
VALUES ('2020-02-06')
      ,('2020-02-07')
      ,('2020-02-08');


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #1

select distinct DS1.[Date]
               ,DS1.[User] 
into #1
from [X].[dbo].[Table1] DS1
INNER JOIN #DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[Date] = DS2.[Date]
where DS1.[status] = 'Success';

select #1.[date]
      ,count(distinct [User])
from #1
inner join [Y].[dbo].[Table2]
  on #1.[User] = [Y].[dbo].[Table2].User
where [Date2] between #1.[date] and #1.[date] + 1
  and [Checkname] in ('Check1','Check2')
GROUP BY #1.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to say that gotqn's answer is a good answer - however, I think there are a few more things in the original code that can be improved - so here is how I would probably do it:

Assuming the dates are consecutive, use a common table expression to calculate the dates using `dateadd` and `row_number`.
Then, use another common table expression to get the list of dates and users from `table1`,
and then select the date and count of distinct users for each date from that common table expression joined to `table2`:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate Date = '2020-02-06';
WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT TOP (60) DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) -1, @StartDate) As Date
    FROM sys.objects
), CTE AS
(
    SELECT t1.[User], t1.[Date]
    FROM [X].[dbo].[Table1] AS t1
    JOIN Dates 
        ON t1.[Date] = Dates.[Date]
    WHERE [status] = 'Success'
)

SELECT cte.[Date], COUNT(DISTINCT [User])
FROM CTE 
JOIN [Y].[dbo].[Table2] As t1
    ON CTE.[User] = t1.[User]
    AND t1.[Date2] >= CTE.[Date]
    AND t1.[Date2] < DATEADD(Day, 1, CTE.[Date])
    AND [Checkname] IN ('Check1','Check2')
GROUP BY cte.[Date]
```

If the dates are not consecutive, you can use a table variable to hold the dates instead of calculating them using a common table expression.